# Reactjs - Conditional dependant dropdown lists with least possible code

Tags: reactjs

I have a React App with a working related dropdown lists. This is my first React App and I do not think the way I have coded is efficient. The code below works fine but I need some expert advise as I am sure its very inefficient.

Basically as an example, when a user selects Religion as Christian, the second dropdown gets triggered and ONLY the castes in Christianity are displayed in the second dropdown. If the user selects religion as Hindu, only the castes in Hindu will be displayed etc...

Here is how I am doing it:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    ...
    import ReligionInput from './religion-input'
    import InputCasteChristian from './caste-christian-input'
    import InputCasteHindu from './caste-hindu-input'
    import InputCasteMuslim from './caste-muslim-input'
    ...
    class EditProfile extends Component {
      state = {
      ...
      ...
      religion,
      caste,
      ...
      render() {
       let {
      ...
      religion,
      caste,
      ...
      } = this.state

        //determine which caste to use
        let casteVariable
        let religionSelected = Object.values({ religion }).toString()
        switch (religionSelected) {
          case 'Christian':
            casteVariable = <InputCasteChristian value={caste} change={this.change} />            
break
          case 'Hindu':
            casteVariable = <InputCasteHindu value={caste} change={this.change} />
            break
          case 'Muslim':
            casteVariable = <InputCasteMuslim value={caste} change={this.change} />
            break
          default:
            casteVariable = ''
        }
    ...
    ...
    <div className="profile_right">
                  <div className="basic_details mb-3">
                    ...
                    ...
                    <ReligionInput value={religion} change={this.change} />
                    {casteVariable}

    const mapStateToProps = store => ({
      ud: store.User.user_details,
      tags: store.User.tags,
      session: store.User.session,
    })


    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProfile)
    export { EditProfile as PureEditProfile }
```

And here is InputCasteChristian

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Select from '../others/input/select'
import christianOptions from './caste-christian-options'

const InputCasteChristian = ({ value, change }) => (
  <div className="edit_caste_div">
    <Select
      placeholder="Select option"
      value={value}
      valueChange={e => change('caste', e)}
      className="edit_caste my2"
    >
      <option value="" disabled selected>
        Select Caste
      </option>
      {christianOptions.map((e, key) => {
       return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>
       })}
    </Select>
  </div>
)

InputCasteChristian.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  change: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default InputCasteChristian
```

The main reason I think this is not efficient is because I am creating a component for each religion - example `<InputCasteChristian`

When I need to implement this same logic for states and their cities, I will end up creating 50 components for each state in the US (for example).

I use MYSQL/PhymyAdmin and I only have one column for religion and one for caste that user selects. There is no lookup table.

I use Redux so storing the values in the state is an option.

Whats the alternate and more efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try normalizing the data inside of your store. For example, consider structure like this:

```
const initialState = {
  selected: {
    state: null,
    city: null
  },
  states: {
    list: [0, 1, 2],
    entities: {
      0: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'state0',
        cities: [0, 3]
      },
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'state1',
        cities: [1, 4]
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'state2',
        cities: [2, 5]
      }
    }
  },
  cities: {
    list: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    entities: {
      0: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'city0'
      },
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'city1'
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'city2'
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
};
```

Doing so will help to avoid bloat inside of your components. Basically, your connected container should look something like this:

```
// ...

class Container extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    selectState: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectCity: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    states: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    cities: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    selected: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  get statesOptions () {
    return this.props.states.list.map(id => this.props.states.entities[id]);
  }

  get citiesOptions () {
    const { states, cities, selected } = this.props;
    const selectedStateCities = states.entities[selected.state].cities;

    return selectedStateCities.map(id => cities.entities[id]);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Select
          options={this.statesOptions}
          value={this.props.selected.state}
          onChange={({ id }) => this.props.selectState(id)}
        />
        <Select
          options={this.citiesOptions}
          value={this.props.selected.city}
          onChange={({ id }) => this.props.selectCity(id)}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// ...
```

Also, to easily normalize data (especially from API responses), check out [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) package. Hope it helps.